# Is a signature on a stapled bag with the restaurant’s bill considered enough of a seal for meat?

Tags: kashrut-kosher

If one were to order delivery and the bag were stapled with the restaurant’s official receipt stapled to the bag and there was also a signature (albeit somewhat illegible) along the opening of the bag, Is this sufficient to eat the meat contained within?

Comment: Even without the psak halacha phrasing, here, no one would know how to answer your question with this information. Any reliable kosher restaurant should be supervised by a Va'ad or Kashrut organization. They dictate the packaging policy for deliveries. When I order something, it is packed with a strong tape surrounding the bag. The tape says something to the effect that if the tape or bag has been tampered in any way, call the food place for a replacement order and do not accept the package. In other words, the package and tape must be opened only by the customer. This ensures the kashrut.

Comment: As a mashgiach, when I seal food, I use tape from the hechsher, with the relevant information and a signature, although different organisations have different standards, so you should ask the va'ad under which the organisation is supervised